# Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Test run failed to complete. Expected 87 tests, received 66'. Check device logcat for details

Tags: android, android-espresso

When I am running the test cases separately test case passes successfully, but when I am running complete test suite the test runner crash showing the above error message.
I have investigated this issue but didn't get the specific answer please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: what in device logcat?

Comment: Thanks for replay!,
I didn't take a complete logcat but the only error message is `Reason: 'Test run failed to complete. Expected 87 tests, received 47'.

Comment: May be a condition in Before or BeforeClass is not when you do test suite

Comment: I have added the code to register the idling resources in the BeforeClass()

@BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() {
        IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(EspressoIdlingResource.getIdlingResource());
    }

Comment: and in the @Before()

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Before
    public void setUp() {

        SharedPreferences.Editor prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()).edit();
        prefs.remove("active_meal_uri").apply();
        logout();
        selectPrefsAndEnvironment(VALUE_ENVIRONMENT_PREPROD);
    }

Comment: This is my added code please verify the let me know your findings.

Comment: Should I have added some extra code?

Comment: First : put your code in your question (it will more clear), second : this may help you I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640028/test-run-failed-test-run-failed-to-complete-expected-1-tests-received-0

Comment: This will also happen if my test will fail. Basically, they have to show the failing exception but runner stops on the failing test cases and the tests are continuously running my device.

Comment: recently I updated my build Gradle dependencies is it related to that because I verified my BeforeClass() and Before() by handling the exception but this is still reprodisable